# How to split by multiple strings in C#

Tags: c#

My Question consists of how might i split a string like this:

```
""List of devices attached\r\n9887bc314\tdevice\r\n12n1n2nj1jn2 
\tdevice\r\n\r\n"
```

Into:

```
[n9887bc314,n12n1n2nj1jn2]
```

I have tried this but it throws the error "Argument 1: cannot convert from 'string' to 'char'"

```
string[] delimiterChars = new string[] {"\\","r","n","tdevice"};
string y = output.Substring(z+1);
string[] words;
words = y.Split(delimiterChars, StringSplitOptions.None);
```

I'm wondering if i'm doing something wrong because i'm quite new at c#.
Thanks A Lot

Comment: `Split` does not accept strings as delimiters, chars only

Comment: Oh sorry i was confused because i saw this by Microsoft https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/programming-guide/strings/how-to-parse-strings-using-string-split

Comment: How would i do this with Chars?

Answer (score 7):

First of all [String.Split  accept strings[] as delimiters](https://learn.microsoft.com/ru-ru/pages/pagetypes/system.string)

Here is my code, hope it will helps:

```
string input = "List of devices attached\r\n9887bc314\tdevice\r\n12n1n2nj1jn2\tdevice\r\n\r\n";
string[] delimiterChars = { 
                            "\r\n",
                            "\tdevice",
                            "List of devices attached"
                          };
var words = input.Split(delimiterChars, StringSplitOptions.RemoveEmptyEntries);
foreach (var word in words)
{
    Console.WriteLine(word);
}
```

Comment: Seems to me, you just need to add `"List of devices attached"` to your `delimiterChars`, so that the output is as shown in question. (thanks to your RemoveEmptyEntries option)

Answer (score 1):

Split the whole string by the word *device* and then remove the tabs and new lines from them. Here is how:

```
var wholeString = "List of devices attached\r\n9887bc314\tdevice\r\n12n1n2nj1jn2\tdevice\r\n\r\n";
var splits = wholeString.Split(new[] { "device" }, StringSplitOptions.RemoveEmptyEntries);
var device1 = splits[1].Substring(splits[1].IndexOf("\n") + 1).Replace("\t", "");
var device2 = splits[2].Substring(splits[2].IndexOf("\n") + 1).Replace("\t", "");
```

Comment: @EliasRC That's not possible. See [here](https://dotnetfiddle.net/U56Nia) a working program.

Comment: @EliasRC I cannot see all your code in that screenshot. What is above the commented out code?

Comment: Here it is bellow in my answer

Comment: @EliasRC Your question was to get the device numbers out of the string and I have answered your question. It seems you have another issue now which you need to figure out.

Comment: Thank you for helping and i appreciate it. You helped me a great deal. Thank you.

Answer (score 1):

I've been doing a first aproach and it works, it might help:
I splited the input looking for "/tdevice" and then cleaned everyting before /r/n including the /r/n itself. It did the job and should work with your adb output.

**EDIT:**
I've refactored my answer to consider @LANimal answer (split using all delimiters) and I tried this code and works. (note the @ usage)

```
static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        var inputString = @"List of devices attached\r\n9887bc314\tdevice\r\n12n1n2nj1jn2\tdevice\r\n\r\n";

        string[] delimiters =  {
                                @"\r\n",
                                @"\tdevice",
                                @"List of devices attached"
                              };
        var chunks = inputString.Split(delimiters, StringSplitOptions.RemoveEmptyEntries);

        string result = "[";

        for (int i = 0; i < chunks.Length; i++)
        {              
                result += chunks[i] + ",";
        }
        result = result.Remove(result.Length - 1);
        result += "]";

        Console.WriteLine(result);
        Console.ReadLine();
    }
```

I hope it helps,

Juan

Answer (score 0):

You could do:

```
string str = @"List of devices attached\r\n9887bc314\tdevice\r\n12n1n2nj1jn2\tdevice\r\n\r\n";    
string[] lines = str.Split(new[] { @"\r\n" }, StringSplitOptions.None);
string firstDevice = lines[1].Replace(@"\tdevice", "");
string secondDevice = lines[2].Replace(@"\tdevice", "");
```

Comment: Thanks for the help but i still get the error on the line with second device

Comment: The error reads @chaosifier Argument 1: cannot convert from 'string' to 'char'

Comment: You can use the exact code I have provided. I've tested it and it doesn't produce any errors. @EliasRC

Comment: And can you provide the full code so that we can know what exactly is causing the problem?

Comment: In which line are you getting the error on? @EliasRC

Comment: The Error is on the line "var device2 = splits[2].Substring(splits[2].IndexOf("\n") + 1).Replace("\t", "");"

Comment: And are you sure the error message is "Argument 1: cannot convert from 'string' to 'char'" ?

Comment: Can you put a breakpoint on the beginning of the Main function and debug through each line to know in which line the error is exactly? Because the said error shouldn't be on the line you're pointing.

Comment: Ok thank you i will do this. Can i chat with you when i find out?

Comment: @EliasRC Ok, sure.